# 'Download' files direct to Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, synchronization

Is there a way to download a `.PDF` or whatever in such a way that it would skip my local machine and be directly uploaded to Google docs?

If that's not possible, is there some solution where I can set up a folder, to download the file to, that will synchronise with Google Docs?

Comment: Related: [On OS X, how do I print (a web-page) directly into my Google Docs account?](http://superuser.com/questions/297714/on-os-x-how-do-i-print-a-web-page-directly-into-my-google-docs-account/297729#297729)

Answer (score 4):

You could map a drive to Google docs with the Gladinet "G-Drive". [Look here](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=1927%2012624351498939350646) in the Google App market place. Then adjust your browser downloads location to the G-Drive.

Answer (score 2):

Make a bookmarklet out of this:
`javascript:var%20url=prompt%28%27URL%20of%20the%20document%20to%20upload:%27,location.href%29;if%28url%29location.href=%27http://docs.google.com/?action=updoc&formsubmitted=true&uploadURL=%27%20encodeURIComponent%28url%29;`

Add it to your bookmarks bar, and paste in the URL of what you want to add. It defaults to the page you're on, but there may be a way to edit it to default it to what's in the clipboard. My javascript powers are lacking.

[Source](http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001717.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Any PDF file accessible as a valid URL can be opened with the Google Docs Viewer](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2010/02/how-to-open-pdf-or-word-doc-file-within.html) & saved to your Google Docs account if you are already signed in.

The URL of the .PDF to be opened within the browser has to be passed to Google Viewer as a querystring value. For example -
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.hud.gov/buying/checklist.pdf

You will notice a button "Save in Google Docs" if you were logged with your Google Account prior to opening the PDF or else you'll need to sign in to save the PDF to Google Docs.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the [Cloud Save](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dlbemabjbfhjcccahjioenmkgimjbbkd) Chrome extension.

> Right Click items on a webpage and save them directly to the cloud. Many cloud storage services are supported.

Google Drive (*née* Google Docs) is one of those supported.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to the kind of issues you seem to be running into. Both are extensions in the Chrome store and may have clones for other browsers.

Viewing without saving:

- Solution: "[Docs PDF/PowerPoint Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn) (by Google, currently v.3.9) - "Automatically previews pdfs, powerpoint presentations, and other documents in Google Docs Viewer"

Dealing with attachments and cluttering your local drive/temp folders:

- Solution: "[Gmail Attachments To Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/epoohehjbaenldfbahgcegdmlogakgin) (currently 1.3.5) - "Save those pesky Gmail attachments directly to Google Drive from the attachment list itself with a newly added Save To Drive link"

Answer (score 0):

You can add and use [*Copy, URL to Google Drive*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-url-to-google-drive/hhkdailooaapiplkadgdkkllbnkjpbel) add-on for *Google Drive*.

> This is a tool that allows you to save or unzip, uncompress any URL (document, file, Google Drive file..) directly to Google Drive.
>
> This apps allow you to do an URL uploading to Google Drive.